# In SQL Alchemy how to use 'on_conflict_do_update' when one use a dictionary for the values

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, fastapi

In SqlAlchemy I want to **insert** a new row in *my_table*, but if the value for the column "name" already exists then I want to **update** this column:

```
dico =     {
  "name": "somename",
  "other_column": "some_value"
}

result = conn.execute(
    insert(my_table.on_conflict_do_update(
        constraint="name",
        set_=dico
    ),
    [ dico ]
)
```

But I get this error:

> 'Insert' object has no attribute 'on_conflict_do_update'

Very important: I need to specify the values for the insert/update as a dictionary.

Thank you

Comment: You need to use the `insert` function provided by the dialect, such as `sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.insert`, assuming the dialect you are using supports on conflict do update.

Comment: Which database are you using? SQLAlchemy supports upsert for several dialects but not all, see https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/queryguide/dml.html#orm-queryguide-upsert

Answer (score 4):

Suppose you have a table like that:

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, String, Integer, UniqueConstraint
from sqlalchemy.orm import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import insert


Base = declarative_base()


class Table(Base):
    __tablename__ = "example"
    __table_args__ = (UniqueConstraint("name"),)
    row_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String, unique=True)
    other_column = Column(String)
```

You can use on_conflict_do_update like that:

```
dico = {
  "name": "somename",
  "other_column": "some_value"
}
stmt = insert(Table).values(dico)
stmt = stmt.on_conflict_do_update(
            constraint="example_name_key",
            set_={col: getattr(stmt.excluded, col) for col in dico}
        )
```

Important to know is that you have to import it from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql
and that stmt.excluded holds the "new" value for your update.

---

EDIT:
To get your constraints dynamically, you can use the inspector.

```
inspector = sqlalchemy.inspect(engine)
inspector.get_unique_constraints(table.__tablename__)  # or provide the table name as a string
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer, I think it's the good way, do you know how can I specify that I want a constraint on any of the UNIQUE columns of the table ? I tried constraint=my_table.UniqueConstraint but does not work... (error: Table' object has no attribute 'UniqueConstraint')

Comment: You have to import UniqueConstraint from sqlalchemy.
And then you can add a constraint in the __table_args__ of your table definition like this `__table_args__ = (UniqueConstraint("column1", "column2", "column3"),)`  <- This states, that the combination of column1, column2, column3 is unique

Comment: Ok but I cannot use ORM (so no __tabl_args__) and I don't know in advance which column has this constraint (my code is dynamic)

Comment: I've edited the post to show how you can use the inspector to get the unique-constraints dynamically